# python - how to get branch name from a specific build from jenkins?

Tags: python, git, python-2.7, jenkins

We use Git, jenkins and python at office.

We build a new SW version on a daily basis using jenkins.

How can I get the branch name to which the build belongs using Python from Jenkins?

**Is there any API (function call) in Jenkins that can I give the build number as an argument, and it gives me the branch number?**

**Temporary solution**

We also have a git tag for each build, in the following format:

```
<build>_<username>_<branch>
```

I currently use the following git command to get the tag:

```
git ls-remote --tags <git-repo> | grep BUILD-NUMBER
```

Once I have the tag, I extract the branch name from it using regex.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check jenkinsapi https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jenkinsapi

With it you can do:

```
>>> from jenkinsapi.jenkins import Jenkins
>>> job_name = 'example_job'
>>> build_number = 123
>>> server = Jenkins('http://localhost:8080', username='user', password='passwd')
>>> build = server.get_job(job_name).get_build(build_number)
>>> rev = build.get_revision_branch()[0].get('name')
>>> print rev
refs/remotes/origin/master
>>> rev.rsplit('/', 1)[1]
'master'
```

Comment: Hi, and if just want to get the "master" word, should I use a regex?

Comment: You can use use [rsplit()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) for that.
'refs/remotes/origin/master'.rsplit('/', 1)[1]

Comment: I have never used a pypy library before. How to use it? I guess I should first download it. Once downloaded, where should I put it, should I install it some how? can you please send a link for how to install pypy package so it can be used?

Comment: Installing Python packages with [pip](https://pip.pypa.io) is handy.  There are a lot of examples in the net about installing Python packages and setting up a Python environment.